# Received segfault when dereferencing iterator which has been initialized to list.begin

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segfault when dereferencing an iterator which has been initiallized to list.begin().

```
list<data>::iterator it;
for(int i=0; i< n; i++)    
{
    it = (list_empty[i]).begin();
    while(it != (list_empty[i]).end())
    {
        cout<<"PROBLEM HERE: size="<<it->process.size<<endl;
        //cout<<"log file i="<<i<<endl;
        log_file_start(current_time, it,"list of empty");
        it++;
    }
}
```

This is the error from the gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to process 2888]
0x0804ecc0 in log_file_buddy (list_delay=..., list_vp=..., 
    list_empty=0x805a00c, method=..., current_time=0, n=10)
    at fuctions_of_mm.cpp:425 
425         cout<<"PROBLEM HERE: size="<<it->process.size << endl;
```

Output of gdb with bt full, shows that iterator is NULL.

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x0804ecc0 in log_file_buddy (list_delay=..., list_vp=..., 
    list_empty=0x805a00c, method=..., current_time=0, n=10)
    at fuctions_of_mm.cpp:425
        i = 8
        it = {_M_node = 0x0}
        out = <incomplete type>
```

Although the iterator is NULL, the `it != (list_empty[i]).end()` is evaluated.
what is wrong?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the omission.
This is it: `list_empty = new list<data>[n];`
N is a parameter given, representing this: 2^{N} = Size_of_Memory

**EDIT #2:**
This is the definition:

```
typedef struct data{
    int position;
    vp proccess;
    int delay;
    int current_life;
    int time_start;
    int time_stop;
    int part_of_memory; 
    bool operator ==(const data& st)
    {
      return proccess.pid == st.proccess.pid;
    }
}data;
```

And the definition of vp:

```
    typedef struct {
    int size;
    int pid;//prosdiorisths diergasias
 }vp
```

**And a value for n: `n = 10`.**

**the declaration of list_empty is list< data > *list_empty; .**

Comment: What is `list_empty`?

Comment: It looks like `list_empty[8]` is not a valid `std::list` object. How was it created, and what happened to it between creation and this code?

Comment: Also, where does `n` come from?

Comment: What is list_empty? Is it a container of containers of some sort? Why do you need an unused it_empty variable? Is this your real code?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I've added the declaration of list_empty, sorry for the omission.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: n is a parameter given (explained at the edit)

Comment: @user2008313 No, you haven't. That's just assignment, not a declaration.

Comment: I think using C++11 could make this pice of code look much simpler. On the other hand...GDB is your friend in such situations...

Comment: @melpomene: I've updated the question with the code needed.

Comment: @user2008313 The declaration of `list_empty` is still missing.

Comment: it = (list_empty[i]).begin();   OR: auto it = (list_empty[i]).begin();  ??  What is it ??

Comment: I've added the declaration of list_empty and I've updated the declaration of it

Comment: The posted code looks OK, your problem probably lies elsewhere. Try running the program with `valgrind`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <list>
using std::list;

const int n = 10;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int pid;//prosdiorisths diergasias
}vp;


typedef struct data{
    int position;
    vp process;
    int delay;
    int current_life;
    int time_start;
    int time_stop;
    int part_of_memory;
    bool operator ==(const data& st)
    {
    return process.pid == st.process.pid;
    }
}data;

int main()
{

    list<data>* list_empty = new list<data>[n];
    list<data>::iterator it;
    for(int i=0; i< n; i++)
    {
        it = (list_empty[i]).begin();
        while(it != (list_empty[i]).end())
        {
            cout<<"PROBLEM HERE: size="<<it->process.size<<endl;
            //cout<<"log file i="<<i<<endl;
            //log_file_start(current_time, it,"list of empty");
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `it`?

```
it_empty = new list<data>::iterator[n];
for(int i=0; i< n; i++)    
{
    auto it = (list_empty[i]).begin();
    while(it != (list_empty[i]).end())
    {
        cout<<"PROBLEM HERE: size="<<it->process.size<<endl;
        //cout<<"log file i="<<i<<endl;
        log_file_start(current_time, it,"list of empty");
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: list < data >::iterator it;

Comment: @user2008313 : Ok. Good. With what code actualy have you the error? Is now OK? Or is still broken?